# Replace a lambda expression as IE is not accepting them

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, lambda, factory

I am currently using a lambda expression on my data calls and it works great on Chrome. I have to make it work on IE as well and IE will not accept them. The code I am using is:

```
myApp.factory('User', ['$resource',
function saveDateFactory($resource) {
  var myData = '';

  //this grabs the data we need for the url below
  function getMyData(data) {
    myData = data;

  }

  //this is where we actually capture the data
  return {
    getMyData: getMyData,
    resource: () => $resource(myData, {}, {
      query: {
        method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: true,
        interceptor: {
          response: function (response) {
            //this is the piece we actually need
            return response.data;
          }
        }
      }
    })
  };
}]);
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can change this so IE will accept it and it still works? Thanks for your help!

Comment: which version of IE you are testing on?

Comment: did my answer helped you? if so, can you please up vote and mark as correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the IE compatibility for ES6 [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). This `() =>` feature is called [ExpressionBodies](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies) and it's not available for IE....

I suggest you to not use this **ES6** features without an interpreter like **[BabelJs](https://babeljs.io)**

```
myApp.factory('User', ['$resource',
function saveDateFactory($resource) {
  var myData = '';

  //this grabs the data we need for the url below
  function getMyData(data) {
    myData = data;
  }

  //this is where we actually capture the data
  return {
    getMyData: getMyData,
    resource: function(){
        $resource(myData, {}, {
        query: {
          method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: true,
          interceptor: {
            response: function (response) {
              //this is the piece we actually need
              return response.data;
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```